# How do I return a value from a spinner in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to use the values that are in a spinner every time a value is selected but when ever i select a value nothing happens.

I have added items into the spinner and there three items in it when you click on it you can see them but when you select one of them nothing happens.

This is my code that i wrote to deal with when one is selected but its not working, am I doing something wrong?

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    fetchUserFollowings()
    //fetchNews()

    //Bind views
    val list = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.followingRecyclerView)

    //create layout manager
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    list.layoutManager = layoutManager


    //Set Dropdown list
    val spinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner)
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(view.context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,
        android.R.id.text1, categories)
    spinner.adapter = adapter


    spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object:AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(
            parent: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View?,
            position: Int,
            id: Long
        ) {
            val selected = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)
            Log.d("TAG", selected.toString())
        }
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            println("nothing selected")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the android logger instead of `println()`. For example: `Log.d("TAG", selected.toString())`. Your code might be working and you are not logging in the logcat or watching the logs in there.

Comment: I still get nothing if i do that

Comment: Please post the rest of the code as I think you don't write the Listener in the right place

Comment: I've included my onViewCreated() method

Comment: You should check out the Android dev guide on spinners, 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

Comment: Your code works fine for me? Change the spinner, get a line in the log. I just threw a ``Spinner`` with that ID into a ``FrameLayout``, so make sure you don't have several and you're not clicking the wrong one, or something. I can't find a problem with what you've posted, anyway